# Understanding scrollr.js cubic bezier

Tags: javascript, css

I was just playing around with the scrollr.js plugin and saw this [demo page](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/docu/3.html). My question is about the animation is initailed on the `WOOOT` div , the code is below:

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);transform[bounce]:rotate(0deg);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);transform[bounce]:rotate(360deg);" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">WOOOT</div>
```

Now notice how a cubic bezier (I think so) is added like so:

```
transform[bounce]:rotate(0deg);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
```

Now what kind of CSS syntax is the above? Or is it just a scrollr.js thing? I know scrollr.js internally defines a few cubic bezier, but I am still confused about the above syntax. If I inspect the element I see no cubic bezier defined on the element. So what is the `[bounce]` really?

There is [documentation for its usage](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#now-lets-do-a-barrel-roll-at-the-same-time), but I want to know what really that syntax is doing behind the scenes, is it adding a CSS cubic bezier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform[bounce]` isn't a CSS property. This is a skrollr-specific syntax for adding an ease to animations, interpreted by the plugin. [From the docs:](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#now-let-the-rotation-bounce-like-it-were-a-hip-hop-video)

> Skrollr allows non-linear animations. The so called easing functions can be used per-property by putting them in square brackets behind the property. There's a built-in list of easing functions (see below in the JavaScript section) and you can use your own functions by using the easings options.

Easing algorithms can be represented as a cubic bezier, but this plugin appears to handle the animation in JavaScript, not using a CSS animation.